# batch: create relative folders based on archives name and only then extract multiple .rar archives in their respective folder

Tags: batch-processing, winrar

I have these .rar/zip archives into `C:\test`

```
test1.rar
test2.rar
```

Inside `test1.rar` I haven't folders, just files while in `test2.rar` I have also a folder inside
I try to extract every rar/zip archives into relative folders with archive content into `C:\test2`. 
I want to use same name of archives for relative folder name

```
test1 <-- in this folder there are only files because test1.rar had not folders within
test2 <-- content should extracted preserving structure folder inside archive
```

Script that I use is this

```
@echo off
set "SourceFolder=C:\test"
set "TargetFolder=C:\test2"
if not exist "%TargetFolder%" md "%TargetFolder%"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\Rar.exe" x -cfg- -idq -r -y "%SourceFolder%\*.rar" "%TargetFolder%"
del /F /Q /S "%SourceFolder%\*.rar">nul
for /D %%D in ("%SourceFolder%\*") do rd "%%D" 2>nul
```

but this script works bad

1. After extraction this script delete my .rar archives from Source Folder, but I don't want this
2. It doesn't create `test1` folder *before* to move `test1.rar` content inside `test1` folder. It simply extract content

THIS is output that I expected

```
C:\test2
   |
   |--- test1 [folder]
   |       |
   |       |--a.txt
   |       |--b.txt
   |
   |--- test2 [folder]
          |
          |--simple [folder]
          |     |
          |     |- c.txt
          |
          |-d.txt
```

But I get this bad output

```
C:\test2
   |
   |
   |--a.txt
   |--b.txt
   |--simple [folder]
          |     |
          |     |- c.txt
          |
          |-d.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is this. Thanks to **@Mofi** for `-ad` switch

```
@echo off
set "SourceFolder=C:\temp"
set "TargetFolder=C:\temp2"
if not exist "%TargetFolder%" md "%TargetFolder%"
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" x -ad -cfg- -idq -r -y "%SourceFolder%\*.rar" "%TargetFolder%"

for /D %%D in ("%SourceFolder%\*") do rd "%%D" 2>nul
```